# File downloaded from Amplify Storage is empty in iOS

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-ios, amplify-flutter

`downloadFile` seems to work fine (there is no errors) but when `readAsString` called content is empty.

Same code works in Android. What might be the difference causing this to happen in iOS?

Using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` for directory doesn't make a difference.

```
final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final key = 'foo/bar.txt';
final file = File('${dir.path}/$key');
await file.create(recursive: true);

final result = await Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
  key: key,
  local: file,
);

print(await result.file.length()); // 0
print(await result.file.readAsString()); // ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the bug in amplify-flutter. The fix is released in [v0.6.8](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/releases/tag/v0.6.8).